# Index and Match with 2 criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, match, lookup, xlookup

I have 2 excel file/ worksheet. One is internally maintained within the company and one is generated from SAP system. My task is to find out if the 2 files are matching or not. If not what is different, the one maintained in Input Data 2 is the correct one. It's a large data set and I don't know how to solve it?
**Input Data 1:**

| SAP Account Nr. | Company Account Nr. |
| --- | --- |
| 6020 | 55300000 |
| 8170 | 55790000 |
| 8180 | 55800000 |
| 8180 | 55850000 |
| 8156 | 56300000 |
| 8151 | 56400000 |
| 8165 | 56500000 |
| 8165 | 56500101 |
| 8100 | 56600000 |
| 8100 | 56650000 |
| 8100 | 56725000 |
| 8100 | 56750001 |

**Input Data 2:**

| Company Account Nr. | SAP Account Nr. |
| --- | --- |
| 55750000 | 6020 |
| 55750000 | 6020 |
| 55760000 | 6020 |
| 55770000 | 6020 |
| 55790000 | 8170 |
| 55800000 | 8180 |
| 55850000 | 8180 |
| 56300000 | 8156 |
| 56400000 | 8151 |
| 56450000 | 8150 |
| 56500000 | 8165 |
| 56500101 | 8165 |
| 56556000 | 8007 |
| 56600000 | 8100 |
| 56650000 | 8100 |

I have attached the screenshot. Can someone please help?

[Input Data 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxG1U.png)

[Input Data 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqiIx.png)

Comment: Please provide the input data in table markdown format, it is not clear to me based on the input data what you want to achieve. Probably you can put your problem in terms of sample data that doesn't require to understand your specific problem

Comment: Hi David. Sorry my question wasn't clear. Let me put this way. I have 2 excel file/ worksheet. One is internally maintained within the company and one is generated from SAP system. My task is to find out if the 2 files are matching or not. If not what is different? Let me edit my original post and share the input data.

Comment: Hi AshSam123, so both columns from Data1 need to match Data2 (correct dataset), and if not find the differences. Please put provide the input data in table markdown format, so it easier to copy the information to reproduce it. You can use this tool: [Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#), copy the data from your Excel to Table Generator, then generate the markdown and finally to your question.

Comment: Hi. I've provided in the table markdown format. I hope this is how you wanted. I am new to this forum and I hope I've used the tool in correct way. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, @AshSam123. Check my answer and let me know if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following in cell `H3`:

```
=LET(refRng, E3:E17&F3:F17, rng, B3:B14&A3:A14, input, A3:B14,
 SORT(FILTER(input,ISERROR(XMATCH(rng, refRng)), "NO MISSING DATA")))
```

and here is the output sorted of missing data in **Data 1**:
[image: sample output file]

`LET` function for easy reading and composition, without `LET` function you can use:

```
=SORT(FILTER(A3:B14,ISERROR(XMATCH(B3:B14&A3:A14,
 E3:E17&F3:F17)), "NO MISSING DATA"))
```

Basically, it searches for non-matches in `rng` from `refRng`. We concatenate both columns because we need to search for a match in both columns. `XMATCH` returns `#N/A` (error) in case of not found, and this is what we want to filter from `input` dataset via `FILTER` function. In case all `rng` elements are found. We use the third input argument of `FILTER` to return the message of non-missing data.

If you want the output with the same order or columns as in **Data 1**, then replace the first input argument of `FILTER` with:

```
HSTACK(INDEX(input,,2), INDEX(input,,1))
```

or

```
CHOOSE({2,1}, INDEX(input,,1), INDEX(input,,2))
```

Comment: Thank you David. It work's, you're a genius :)